# Zero Knowledge Example using discrete log

Tags: authentication, zero-knowledge-proofs

I've been exploring Zero Knowledge Proofs and while the [classic cave example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof#Abstract_example) by Jean-Jacques Quisquater makes sense, I find the [discrete log example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof#Discrete_Log_of_a_given_value) problematic.

Since the Verifier is given ***p***, ***g*** and ***y***, where ***p*** is a large prime, ***g*** the generator and ***y* = *g <sup>x</sup>* mod *p***. The value ***x*** is secret. My problem is that that there is leakage of information since ***y*** depends directly on the secret ***x***.

Alternatively, the security is that of the discrete algorithm problem. Is this a poor example or do all realizable ZKP leak information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A zero-knowledge proof is a protocol by which the Prover demonstrate to the Verifier that he knows the solution to a given problem, without giving to the Verifier any additional information about the solution -- that is, no information that the Verifier could not already obtain alone. In the case of the discrete logarithm, the *y* value is not part of what the Prover sends; it is a given. The *base problem* consists in (*p*,*g*,*y*) and what the Prover tries to demonstrate is that he knows the corresponding *x* -- but **without helping** the Verifier find out *x*.

The Verifier can always try to solve the problem by himself. This is in fact unavoidable: since a ZK proof is about proving knowledge of a solution to a given problem, anybody can, conceptually, try to solve the problem upfront, if only by exhaustive search of all possible bit patterns for a solution.

This does not count as a leak because it is not information obtained *from the Prover*. It is part of the context. It is information that everybody already has. The whole of ZK is about demonstrating knowledge of some value without yielding *extra* information that was not already public knowledge.

(Honestly I never understood why the cave example was all the rage. It is an analogy and it breaks down when looked at too closely. For instance, Victor could say to Peggy: enter the left corridor, and exit from the right one. This would demonstrate that Peggy knows how to open the door, and would be vastly simpler than the pseudo-ZK concocted for that example.)

Answer (score 0):

Zero knowledge property here is simulator availability that produces indistinguishable protocol transcript. In other words, proving party can deny being ever engaged in a protocol.

One would use Pedersen commitments to avoid leaking any information about his secret.

Answer (score -4):

From y you don't get any information about x, because of the 'mod p' part, which makes the result y random.

Comment: This is so wrong; given $g$, $p$, $g^x \bmod p$, it is easy for a computationally unbounded adversary to recover $x$.  We believe it is infeasible for a practical adversary to do it if we select $g$, $p$ correctly; however that's because the algorithms we know require more computation than we have at our disposal; the information is all there -- we just don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Well, if you assume a computationally unbounded adversary then many problems (DDH, CDH) become easy which are used in security reduction of many cryptographic protocols.

Comment: You stated that 'you don't get any information about x, because ... the result y [is] random"; that is a claim about informational security -- I just mentioned that it is not accurate.  And, in any case, this really isn't an answer to the question; see Thomas's response for the correct answer ("it isn't that $g^x \bmod p$ doesn't leak any data, but that a ZKP doesn't leak any *additional* information")

Comment: @sayan, then you should state your assumption on computationally bounded adversary as "don't get any information" sounds like you are talking about information theoretic security (i.e., computationally unbounded)

Comment: Okay, I admit, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: BTW, please don't get discouraged by the down votes on the answer. I noticed in your profile that you are very interested in crypto. We are glad to have you here. Check out the [Help Center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help) to learn about the scope of this SE site.